# Neo4J query with Huge database very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a database with 29M nodes and 43M relationships

i need to do a query to find a name of an Artist

```
MATCH (a:Artist) WHERE toLower(a.name) CONTAINS toLower("John") AND a.group=false
WITH a
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[b:IS_SUBSCRIBED]->(c:Company)
WITH a, c
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)<-[f:HAS_MEMBER]-(g:Artist)
WITH a, c, collect([g.name, g.aid]) as groups
RETURN a.name AS name, a.aid as id, c.number as aie_number, c.email as email, groups
ORDER BY a.name
LIMIT 200
```

So i have some artists that maybe are subscribed with a company and maybe are members of some groups.
I need to catch that information and when i do the query this take long time, more that 6 seconds that for my point of view is a bit slow, i have attached the profile

[image]

Are there some tricks to improve the performance?

I have INDEX for the Artist name and an index of :Artist(name, group)

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although you have an index because you are doing `toLower` on the `name` property before the comparison then the index is not being used. The first step of the profile shows `NodeByLabelScan`. It is doing a full table scan on the `name` property.

Create a new property on your `:Artist` nodes called `name_lower`, set it to be `toLower(name)`, index that property and use it in your searches. This will vastly improve the performance of your query.

Comment: Sublime answer @Dave